# How to prove $p\land q\to \neg r \vdash r \to p \to \neg q$ using natural deduction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm having a lot of trouble proving the sequent below with Natural Deduction rules. I'm new to this and find it difficult to come up with proof strategies. The first thing I do is to assume $r$ but really confused on where I could go from there.

The sequent:
$$(p\land q)\to \neg r \vdash r \to (p \to \neg q)$$

Thanks so much, any help appreciated!

Comment: What are the rules you can use regarding negation and implication ?

Comment: @FiMePr I can use all the basic rules of natural deduction

Comment: do you mean that $r\to(p\to\neg q)$ ?

Comment: So, what you want to prove is $r, p, (p\wedge q \rightarrow \neg r) \vdash \neg q$, right ?

Comment: @mshoosterman Yes that's what I mean

Comment: Can you use something along the lines of $(A \rightarrow B), \neg B \vdash \neg A$ ?

Comment: http://users.ox.ac.uk/~logicman/carr/NDpack.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step seems good, assume $r$ Now you want to show that $p\to\neg q$, so what do you want to do? well you are trying to prove an implication again, so assume $p$ and show $\neg q$!

You are given that $p\wedge q\to \neg r$ if you already have that $(a\to b) \leftrightarrow (\neg b \to \neg a)$ then this would be a good place to use it. If you dont have this, then you can prove $\neg(p\wedge q)$ using contradiction. (using the fact that you are assuming $r$)

once you have $\neg(p\wedge q)$ you can now just assume $p$ and prove $\neg q$ again by contradiction by assuming $q$.

Comment: Let me know if this is enough, or if you would like a little bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this step and that this is the procedure I need to follow. However whats confusing me is getting from $p$ to $\neg q$. Could you give more detail? Thanks!

Comment: I have added a bit more detail, hope this helps!

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm still unable to prove this! I took all your tips but I just can't reason this out!

Comment: I would suggest then looking at your notes, lecture slides or textbook at other examples of deductions to get a handle on how deductions work in general.I could give you a full solution if you really want, but I dont think this will help you, as the answer I have given is already very close to a full solution. So given that you still cannot get it, it seems like your issue is not with this question, instead its with how to do deductions in general.

Comment: In natural deduction, to derive $\lnot q$, you assume $q$ trying to derive a contradiction. $$\small\def\fitch#1#2{~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{(p\land q)\to\lnot r}{\fitch{r}{\fitch{p}{\fitch{q}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\lnot q}\\p\to\lnot q}\\r\to(p\to\lnot q)}$$